# ًWhy url reverse parts when contains arabic words?

Tags: php, .htaccess

i'm working in php mvc project
and that is the structure of the link to article page

```
<a href="category/<?=$category_data['id'] ?>/
                 <?=$category_data['name'] ?>/
                 <?=$article['id'] ?>/
                <?=$article['title'] ?>">
                <?=$category_data['name']?>
</a>
```

when category name and article title in english words url appear with out any proplems 
http://localhost/tanta/category/4/categoryname/7/articletitle
but when it in arabic words url parts replace its positions
[http://localhost/tanta/category/اسم](http://localhost/tanta/category/%D8%A7%D8%B3%D9%85) القسم/4/9/عنوان المقال
and that is caused proplems in my routing

it is my .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to the arabic language being written right-to-left rather than left-to-right. In order to display this properly a [right to left mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark) is being added to the text.

My advise is to either convert the arabic to the latin alfabet, or strip out any special characters in your URL. (You should always strip special characters)